# Java elegant way of executing methods until condition met

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I have method with a variable `listElement` I initialize  with null and want to execute up to 9 different methods on a certain list (the method input), until I find a value I can overwrite `listElement` with.

If it's not null anymore, I don't want to execute the rest of the methods. If none of the methods find a variable to overwrite with, I want to return null.

Sample:

```
    public XXX findListElement(List<XXX> listsOfxxx) {

    XXX listElement = null;

    listElement = firstMethod(listsOfxxx);
    listElement = secondMethod(listsOfxxx);
    listElement = thirdMethod(listsOfxxx);
    listElement = fourthMethod(listsOfxxx);
    listElement = fifthMethod(listsOfxxx);
    ...

    return listElement;
}
```

How do I skip the rest of the methods, if the first method already finds my variable?
The idea behind this is checking Poker hand strength from Straight Flush to High Card, if I found a Straight Flush inside my list of possible combinations, I don't want to check for Four of a Kind, since they are beaten by the Straight Flush anyway. Then I can simply return the found Straight Flush as the strongest combination of that player.

Comment: By using conditional statements, no doubt.

Comment: That's why I asked about a more elegant way, I don't really want to put 9 if clauses and 10 returns inside that method.

Comment: Use a class instead pure method and initialize a list with the class (like FindMyStuff class with method find()) add the 10 classes to the list then use a foreach every time when searching for smthing.

Comment: I don't think it's worth it in this specific scenario.  I don't need 9 different classes for all possible Poker combination types because they all use the same methods. I could work with generalizations but for me it's a lot simpler to check the list up to 9 times and return the best combination.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the Streams API.

```
    return Stream.<Function<List<Xxx>, Xxx>>of(this::firstMethod,
                                               this::secondMethod,
                                               this::thirdMethod)
                 .map(f -> f.apply(listOfXxx))
                 .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                 .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend you the [chain of responsibility design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)

Another examples:

- [from java.dzone.com](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-uncovered-chain-of-responsibility)
- [from tutorialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/chain_of_responsibility_pattern.htm)

Comment: You may want to describe how "chain of responsibility" pattern fits here, because if it does, it's far from being obvious.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - could you please explain why it does not fit here?
I might misunderstand the question but if I don't then Pulz wants to manage something with a chain of handlers where handlers can decide if they can find (handle) the proper element or they can pass the request forward to the next handler